# What is extra_options param in Rails render method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

`render(options = nil, extra_options = {}, &block) protected` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render)

What is `extra_options` params for? How does it differ to `options` parameter?

Comment: did you notice that the render method under ActionController was used in rails version  <= 2.3 ?. the new render methods are under ActionView

Comment: @Alireza ouch, just noticed that. But why the docs is much more complete on the deprecated ActionController/Base/render's one? I can't infer any useful informations from the docs of the new method.

Comment: The render method has been split up. so now you have PartialRendere to render partials. link:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/PartialRenderer

Comment: Btw, Rails docs still refers to ActionController::Base.render http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Answer (score 0):

The options are passed down the call chain, hitting the Formatter at the end.

For example, if you use the JSON formatter, you will end up giving the parameters to `as_json`, and params docs can be found [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html).

Thus, look for the formatter doc to find the params doc.